# Move uploaded file from one pc to another

Tags: php, file-upload

i am new here and i want to ask something about PHP.
I want to make a server in one pc with xampp and connected to others pc via LAN network. is there a way when uploading a file (ex: pdf file) to this server pc folder?

i have already tried using IP such as move_uploaded_file($_SERVER['SERVER_ADDR'].
/prima/pdf/" and i got an error from validation.

Comment: So, to which PC you want to transfer? The PC which has XAMPP server or to the PC connected with LAN?

Answer (score 0):

**No** (http://php.net/manual/en/function.move-uploaded-file.php).

All You can do is to upload file normally to one server, and then use php to send it further, and after success, remove it from ogirinal server.

---

Take a look at ssh2_connect() - http://php.net/manual/en/function.ssh2-connect.php, and ssh2_scp_send() - http://php.net/manual/en/function.ssh2-scp-send.php.

---

You can also use exec() - http://php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php, to connect via ssh or scp and send file elsewhere, or run Your own bash script for this.

---

*But this is a solution that is far from perfect, got many possible security holes (password storing for connection, etc).*

If You **must** do something like this, in my opinion there is a huge "misconception", and you should rewrite your application graph, and think about another solution. Another: I mean one-server solution, or completely new strategy for handling this.

---

If you will write something more (why, for what?) maybe someone will help you to fine "easier and safer" solution.

Answer (score 0):

If you have permission to write on a shared network folder you just need to point to the shared folder you desire.